# Sending a complex object from Java client to C server via Socket

Tags: java, c, sockets, tcp

I want to send some complex objects from a Java client to C server via a TCP Socket.

How can I do that ?

Comment: What do you expect a **c** server to do with the internal representation of a java object?

Comment: Are you writing the client? server? both?

Comment: @PabloMaurin I am writing both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fundamentally the question is, "*How to serialize/deserialize objects in a
language agnostic manner?*"  Specifically Java and C in your case.  Since you'll
be sending this data over a network, it is also important to take care of [network order/endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) issues.

I assume you have access to both the the client and the server.  This means you
get to choose how to serialize the data.  (If not, the answer is simple.  Write
to the specs of what the other is expecting)

Personally, I would use [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/).
There are [Java bindings](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java-generated)
and [C bindings](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-c/).

If you don't like Protocol Buffers, there are other options like:

- [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) (already mentioned)
- [YAML](http://yaml.org/)
- Apache [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/)
- [XDR](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4506)
- roll your own
- ...

Comment: Yes I have access to both.
Between these which is the better solution (the fastest) ?

Comment: There's no need to worry about endianness unless you're dumping raw memory to the network.  See Rob Pike's excellent discussion at http://commandcenter.blogspot.com/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html  (In case the name isn't familiar, Pike is one of the inventors of Unix.)

Answer (score 3):

Write the fields of the Java objects to a string (perhaps [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)), send them via TCP, and have the C program read the string and use it to initialize new C variables on the other end.

Comment: I have already thought about this solution. But I am stuck in sending strings from java to C. The only thing that I succeded to send is a Char. I though about : 
1-sending an integer that represent the length of the string. 
2-Do a dynamic allocation 
2-Send the String character by character  
The problem that I am convinced that this solution will be slow and not performant.
So what do you think ?

Comment: For performance, you want to send as much data in one packet as you can, but it's completely up to you how to _represent_ that data.  For example, you can send the number 160 as one binary `A0` byte, or you can send it as the 3 characters `1`, `6`, `0`, or you can invent some other representation.  The only thing that matters is that the sender and receiver agree on the representation. And you can guarantee that, because you have control over both ends.  @Pablo Maurin's suggestion to use protocol buffers is very reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

This question is pretty old, but just in case some one is still looking for a good solution, you can try out the protocol buffers implementation, as mentioned in the previous answer by @Adam Liss: (developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/)

In short, you define any complex message type as in your protocol implementation, and the tool generates C++/Java/Python code which can serialize and deserialize it.

For the same purpose using C code, a research project at the Technische Universität München (TUM) Germany have created a code generator in standard C, that can be used with embedded-C projects. This is fully compatible(with limitations due to C structs) with Google's protobuf implementation. This works better than the [C Bindings](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-c/) because it does not need any library to be linked with.
I had issues in getting the [C Bindings](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-c/) to work on the embedded systems I was working with, because it needs to be linked with the support library.

This saved my (painful) day with my embedded project - passing complex network data(request-responses) between an embedded system and Android app(Java)/Desktop app(C++/Qt).